# Where can I find simple usage examples?

Tags: словоупотребление, обучение, resources

When learning a new word I like to see typical usage examples.  The sort of thing you find in a good dictionary.  However, even my big old Oxford Russian dictionary had nothing for *вовлечь*, for example, and in any case I can't carry that around with me.

I have tried searching ruscorpora.ru but it's hard to find examples that are simple enough for me to understand.

Comment: When I have troubles with English words usage, I just google them :)

Comment: If you can't find simple enough examples elsewhere and are desperate, a good place to request simple realistic examples is [the Russian Stackexchange](http://russian.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Очень крутой сайт!

Answer (score 4):

Did you try [ABBYY Lingvo.Pro](http://lingvopro.abbyyonline.com/en)? They can show [examples](http://lingvopro.abbyyonline.com/en/Examples/en-ru/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C) and [phrases](http://lingvopro.abbyyonline.com/en/Phrases/ru-en/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C).

Answer (score 2):

Try searching at http://tatoeba.org/ - the examples are crowdsourced so you might come upon some inconsistencies every once in a while but it is still a formidable resource.

Comment: I wonder if they thought of a Russian section when picking the domain name...

Comment: The site was initially Japanese-English only, hence the name (たとえば, *tatoeba*, 'for example') and the prevalence of Japanese base sentences from the extensive Tanaka corpus in their database, but they are quickly expanding other languages as well.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, try to go to Google or Yandex (yandex.ru is the biggest search engine in Russia).

Also, the site [Master Russian](http://masterrussian.com) has realistic example sentences for common Russian words.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to find typical usage examples is National Russian Corpora - www. ruscorpora.ru or - in english http://ruscorpora.ru/en/index.html
Mind that you can customize subcorpora ( if you need modern usage for example), or search collocations or grammatical patterns. You can also download results or see them in Key-word-in-context view.